# how to insert dynamic data in sqlite3 using python

Tags: python, sqlite

```
enter code here

import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('tutorial.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
c.execute("CREATE TABLE example(Language VARCHAR, Version REAL, Skill 
TEXT)")

def enter_data():
c.execute("INSERT INTO example VALUES('Python', 2.7, 'Beginner')")
c.execute("INSERT INTO example VALUES('Python', 3.3, 'Intermediate')")
c.execute("INSERT INTO example VALUES('Python', 3.4, 'Expert')")
conn.commit()

def enter_dynamic_data():
lang = input("What language? ")
version = float(input("What version? "))
skill = input("What skill level? ")

c.execute("INSERT INTO example (Language, Version, Skill) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", 
(lang, version, skill))

conn.commit()


enter_dynamic_data()

conn.close()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "C:\Users\karti\Desktop\sqlite3\0304 -  inserting dynamic data.py", line 25, in <module>
    enter_dynamic_data()
  File "C:\Users\karti\Desktop\sqlite3\0304 -  inserting dynamic data.py", line 20, in enter_dynamic_data
    c.execute("INSERT INTO example (Language, Version, Skill) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (lang, version, skill))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: example
```

how to eliminate this error?

Comment: Please format your traceback. Also formatting your source code is broken.

Comment: try running the `create_table` function before inserting data in to the table, the error is telling you the table doesn't exist

Comment: Cannot reproduce when first calling `create_table` or when using a database where the table exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message indicates that the table **example** does not exist. You do not appear to be calling **create_table** (or **enter_data**)

Try using :-

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('tutorial.db')
c = conn.cursor()


def create_table():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example(Language VARCHAR, Version REAL, Skill TEXT)") #<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED


def enter_data():
    c.execute("INSERT INTO example VALUES('Python', 2.7, 'Beginner')")


create_table() #<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
enter_data() #<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
c.execute("INSERT INTO example VALUES('Python', 3.3, 'Intermediate')")
c.execute("INSERT INTO example VALUES('Python', 3.4, 'Expert')")
conn.commit()


def enter_dynamic_data():
    lang = input("What language? ")
    version = float(input("What version? "))
    skill = input("What skill level? ")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO example (Language, Version, Skill) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
          (lang, version, skill))
    conn.commit()
enter_dynamic_data()

cursor = c.connection.cursor() #<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM example") #<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
for row in cursor: #<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
    print("Language=", row[0], " Version=", row[1], " Skill=", row[2]) #<<<<<<<<<< ADDED

conn.close()
```

The above results in :-

> ```
> What language? Basic
> What version? 3
> What skill level? Easy
> Language= Python  Version= 2.7  Skill= Beginner
> Language= Python  Version= 3.3  Skill= Intermediate
> Language= Python  Version= 3.4  Skill= Expert
> Language= Basic  Version= 3.0  Skill= Easy
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ```